# Custom info about FrameworkElement

Tags: c#

I'm creating a paint simular program. I Draw System.Windows.Shapes, to a canvas in a UserControl. However I Can name my shapes using the `Line l = new Line; l.Name` Now I would Like to add more than one name to this Line l, Maybe 10 diffrent names. How can I do this? I Have had some ideas but they are all very complicated.

Maybe I was a bit unclear. Example. `l.Name = "name_1"; l.Name2 = "material2";` I need to be able to tie my FrameworkElement with these other names. However I don't need to be able to find an FrameworkElement with these other names.

The ideas that I have came up with is very complicated. One of those is to put the FrameworkElement Name to ID_xxxx, and print this ID to a textfile and then add more information about this ID in this text file. Then to read this I Will read lines between etc ID_1 and ID_2 and then figure out what "material" ID_1 is. This feels very complicated and stupid, so I figured StackOverflow might have some suggestions for me.

Thanks Mikael Törnqvist

Comment: What purpose are you using the names for?

Comment: Edited post a bit, I Want to be able to read My own info about the FrameworkElement. List<string> Names? How can i use this?
My experience with c# Is veery Limited.